# Image conversion bash script not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

I found this script to convert images to webp format.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# converting JPEG images
find $1 -type f -and \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" \) \
-exec bash -c '
webp_path=$(sed 's/\.[^.]*$/.webp/' <<< "$0");
cwebp -quiet -q 90 "$0" -o "$webp_path";
rm -rf $webp_path;' {} \;
```

The folder which is provided as input is as below.

```
root@ip-10-0-1-46:/var/images/newlocallego/12345# tree
.
└── 01234
    ├── 001.jpg
    ├── 002.jpg
    ├── index.htm
    └── main.jpg

1 directory, 4 files
```

i am executing as `./webpconvert.sh /var/images/newlocallego/12345`

However, its neither creating the webp files nor removing the jpg files and not giving any error. What am i missing.

Comment: I don't know what `cwebp` does, but if it's writing to `$webp_path`, then you are immediately removing that afterwards.  You could also get rid of `sed` with `webp_path=${0%.*}.webp`.

Comment: damn. yes, you are right.. i am removing the converted images. i should be removing the original files which are referenced by $0. It works now.. Thank you.

Comment: Quoting in the script is not right. In [unfortunate circumstances](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618) this `rm -rf` may remove a lot. Even if the original author wanted to remove the file just created, I wonder why they used `-r`.

Comment: a contributing factor: the `'` after `sed` closes the `'` after `-exec bash -c`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are immediately removing your output file after creating it.  You also have issues with quoting in the `bash -c` script's command substitution around `sed`, and there are a few instances of variables not being quoted at all.

Corrected variant:

```bsh
find "$@" -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        cwebp -quiet -q 90 -o "${pathname%.*}.webp" -- "$pathname" &&
        rm -f -- "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

This makes the operation more efficient by calling `bash -c` with batches of found files instead of once per file.

The original file is not removed unless `cwebp` exited successfully. The `.webp` filename suffix replaces the original filename suffix by means of a standard parameter substitution, rather than by using `sed`.  Note that `-r` is not needed with `rm` when removing files.

The script now also support taking multiple directories on the command line.

Without using `find`, in `bash`:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob nocaseglob
shopt -s globstar

for dirpath do
    for pathname in "$dirpath"/**/*.{jpg,jpeg}; do
        [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue
    
        cwebp -quiet -q 90 -o "${pathname%.*}.webp" -- "$pathname" &&
        rm -f -- "$pathname"
    done
done
```

The only difference is that this `bash` loop would also process symbolic links to regular files matching the patterns. If that is an issue, then change the `-f` test in the inner loop to

```bsh
if [ ! -f "$pathname" ] || [ -h "$pathname" ]; then
    continue
done
```